# Find author of python file from docstring

Tags: python, python-3.x, docstring

I'm trying to write a program which has a function that finds and prints the author of a file by looking for the `Author` string in the docstring. I've managed to get the code below to print the author of a file that has the author string followed by the authors name and also the author string not followed by a name. The thing I'm having problems with is trying to print `Unknown` when the author string does not exist at all i.e. no part of the docstring contains `Author`.

N.B. `lines` is just a list constructed by using `readlines()` on a file.

```
 def author_name(lines):
    '''Finds the authors name within the docstring'''
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith("Author"):
            line = line.strip('\n')
            line = line.strip('\'')
            author_line = line.split(': ')
            if len(author_line[1]) >=4:   
                print("{0:21}{1}".format("Author", author_line[1])) 
            else:
                print("{0:21}{1}".format("Author", "Unknown"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing a function, then return a value. Do not use print (that is for debugging only). Once you use `return`, you can return early if you do find the author:

```
def author_name(lines):
    '''Finds the authors name within the docstring'''
    for line in lines:
        name = 'Unknown'
        if line.startswith("Author"):
            line = line.strip('\n')
            line = line.strip('\'')
            author_line = line.split(': ')
            if len(author_line[1]) >=4:   
                name = author_line[1]
            return "{0:21}{1}".format("Author", name)  # ends the function, we found an author

    return "{0:21}{1}".format("Author", name)

print(author_name(some_docstring.splitlines()))
```

The last `return` statement only executes if there were no lines starting with `Author`, because if there was, the function would have returned early.

Alternatively, because we default `name` to `Unknown`, you can use `break` as well to end the loop early and leave returning to that last line:

```
def author_name(lines):
    '''Finds the authors name within the docstring'''
    for line in lines:
        name = 'Unknown'
        if line.startswith("Author"):
            line = line.strip('\n')
            line = line.strip('\'')
            author_line = line.split(': ')
            if len(author_line[1]) >=4:   
                name = author_line[1]
            break  # ends the `for` loop, we found an author.

    return "{0:21}{1}".format("Author", name)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the help I needed